# Chef-vault - not creating vaults with create command, but creating simple data bags

Tags: cloud, chef-infra, orchestration, databags, chef-vault

I am trying to create a chef-vault to store some password using below command:

```
knife vault create revrecsecrets revrecpass -A "revrec-validator,node1,node2,node3" -J data_bags/revrecpass.json -M client
```

Where revrecpass.json contains:

```
{ "oracle_pass":"welcome1", "ora_db_passwd":"Welcome1", "weblogic_pass":"welcome1"}
```

I have 3 clients :

```
#knife client list
node1
node2
node3
revrec-validator
```

But Now while trying to access the vault, its saying no vault:

```
# knife vault list
```

Returns nothing.

And :

Trying to refresh : (says vault doesnot exists)

```
# knife vault refresh revrecsecrets revrecpass
ERROR: ChefVault::Exceptions::ItemNotFound: revrecsecrets/revrecpass does not exist, use 'knife vault create' to create.
```

Trying to recreate :(saying already exists)

```
# knife vault create revrecsecrets revrecpass -A "revrec-validator,node1,node2,node3" -J data_bags/revrecpass.json -M client
ERROR: ChefVault::Exceptions::ItemAlreadyExists: revrecsecrets/revrecpass already exists, use 'knife vault remove' 'knife vault update' or 'knife vault edit' to make changes.
```

I am not able to figure out, what is the issue here ? Have anyone faced similar issue OR any suggestion will be thankful.

```
ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
knife --version
Chef: 12.4.1
/opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem list chef-vault

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

chef-vault (2.9.0)
```

Comment: did you ever figured it out? I can't even create a regular vault